# Template class non-templated method argument

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-classes

I have a class which uses templates. It is something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class a
{

public:
    a(T arg);
    a<T> func(a arg); // This seems to work, but...
    a<T> func(a<T> arg); // ...should I be doing this instead?

private:
    T local;
};
```

Notice the two function templates for `func`. Both will compile (of course, not at the same time) but which one is correct, or does it not matter? In the first, I have specified that `class a` is the argument... In this first case, can a different type be used in place of T... For example can I do this:

```
a<float> b;
a<int> c;
a<int> d;
d = c+ b;
```

I am guessing the answer is "no" because it doesn't compile!

In the second case, it is clear that the argument must have the same type templated.

Due to what I discussed above, I am guessing the compiler actually interprets `a<T> func(a arg);` as `a<T> func(a<T> arg);`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class template `a` means `a<All the tempalte args here>` i.e `a<T>`

So both your functions are same.

If you want provide another type you should use template function

```
template <typename T> {
class a {
    template<typename U>
    a<T> func(a<U> arg);
}
```

You may also consider return `std::common_type<T, U>::type` but in your case it'll not compile because common type for `float` and `int` is `float`

```
a<float> x = a<int>(1) + a<float>(8)
```

should work in that case